# SDL2 Mixer: "No SoundFonts have been requested"

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I can't open audio device, my code is very simple:

```
Mix_Init(...);
Mix_OpenAudio(44100, AUDIO_U16SYS, 1, 16);
```

And error from `Mix_GetError()`:

```
No SoundFonts have been requested
```

Any ideas why? My OS is Linux Mint 17 x64, SDL2 come from repository.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is caused by a dependency on FluidSynth, which requires a sound font to be selected at startup.

From [the patch](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_mixer/file/4b699c9a269d/music.c):

> Because the backend is determined when `Mix_OpenAudio` is called,
>   `Mix_SetSoundFonts` needs to be called before this.

It may be possible to disable MIDI in order to avoid having to specify a sound font.

Comment: Thanks for answer, sadly this functions are not documented anywhere. I'll stop using SDL_Mixer.